# Convert Array of Symbols to Array of 1 and 0

Tags: python, arrays, artificial-intelligence

Suppose we have an array/string of stock symbols: ['AMD','AMZN','BABA','FB']. 
I need to be able to convert the supplied stock symbol to 1 and others to 0.

For example if we supplied 'AMZN' to the array above the resulting array should look: [0,1,0,0]. If 'FB' result should look like [0,0,0,1].

I need to feed it into an AI algorithm.

Comment: Please also include whatever you're tried so far and where specifically you are encountering problems.

Comment: tried googling to find an answer

Answer (score 3):

```py
def get_binary_array(input_array, stock_ticker):
    return [1 for thing in input_array if thing == stock_ticker else 0]
```

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
arr = ['AMD','AMZN','BABA','FB']
value = 'AMD'
one_hot = [int(value==i) for i in arr]
```

Comment: thank you for your help!